# NoReverseMatch for named URL with keyword arguments

Tags: django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

**Error shown:**

```
Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'username': 'admin', 'group_name':'laravel', 'pk': ''}' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P<username>[^/]+)/groups/(?P<group_name>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/posts/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/general/$']
```

---

group_list.html
This is a generic ListView template.

```
...
{% for group in object_list %}
    {% with group.post_set.all|first as post %}
        <a href="{% url 'post_detail' username=user.username group_name=group.name_slug pk=post.pk %}">{{ group.name }}</a>
    {% endwith %} 
{% endfor %}
...
```

---

**Main issue:** 
In the template file, all three of the arguments are displayed correctly i.e. **{{ user.username }} {{ group.name_slug }} {{ post.pk }}**.
But, if they are passed in as keyword argument in the named URL, one of the three is empty, and other two correctly passed.

---

**Note:**
There is no space between individual URL keyword arguments.

Comment: `group.post_set.all|first` what if there is _no_ object in that queryset...? That is what is happening and why you are receiving the error.

Comment: `{{ post.pk }}` had shown the primary key, which shows there is a queryset.

Comment: You do realize you have written this in a _loop_ over `object_list` yes? Meaning out of multiple groups one can have a post whose pk gets displayed and another may not... Did you _try_ the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The `first` filter returns an empty string in case an `IndexError` is raised. Hence what is happening there is that there is *no* related post for your group and hence `post.pk` is resolved to an empty string. You should check before using the object:

```
...
{% for group in object_list %}
    {% with group.post_set.all|first as post %}
        {% if post %}
            <a href="{% url 'post_detail' username=user.username group_name=group.name_slug pk=post.pk %}">{{ group.name }}</a>
        {% else %}
            No Posts here!
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %} 
{% endfor %}
...
```

Comment: {{ post.pk }} displayed the primary key of the post.
Passing the keyword arguments only showed empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined an `app_name` in the `urls.py` file? If so you must be sure to add this `app_name` before the url.

Example:

**urls.py**

`app_name = 'my_app'`

**template_name.html**

`<a href="{% url 'my_app:post_detail' username=user.username group_name=group.name_slug pk=post.pk %}">`